# Got a warning require_one whe Deploying a Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

I've just deployed my Symfony2 project and I ame getting the following warning:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/u956719034/public_html/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u956719034/public_html/web/app.php on line 6
```

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/u956719034/public_html/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.3/pear') in /home/u956719034/public_html/web/app.php on line 6

I don't know why it's happening even if I've tried 5.3 ,5.4 and 5.5 php versions?

Comment: What about "No such file or directory" is unclear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, it's solved now...
I cleared the cache and everything is Ok, but now i got an SQL exception...
Here's a hint: in local, in my database i have"article" table and everything is going well, but Now on online server is telling me "that he can't find Article table", I guess the system is getting case sensitive?

Comment: please, post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Update your project via composer like

```
composer update
```